# Using Pipe for images in Windows PowerShell

Tags: image, powershell, ffmpeg

I am trying to pipe images using windows Powershell

```
Get-Content  test_*.bmp  | .\ffmpeg  -framerate 1 -i -   -c:v libx264 -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y video.mp4
```

Unfortunately, everything is working fine except that the resulting video is corrupted.

Then I tried a simple command in PowerShell like this:

```
Get-Content  test.bmp  > simple.bmp
```

This is corrupting the image very similar to the video I created earlier.

Is there a method to PIPE **images** to FFmpeg using Windows Powershell?

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not in front of a computer at the moment to test that out but try adding the '' -raw switch parameter to get-content.

Comment: Maybe by specifying the encoding to byte in addition to the `-raw ` switch `Get-Content -Path 'FilePath' -Encoding byte -Raw`

Comment: What is the single hyphen in your ffmpeg command line for?

Comment: In short: As of PowerShell 7.2, output from external programs is invariably decoded _as text_ before further processing, which means that raw byte output cannot be captured with `>`, for instance. See the linked duplicate for details. The workaround is to call your external program via `cmd /c` (Windows) / `sh -c` (Unix-like platforms) and use _their_ `>` operators.

Comment: @Theo single hyphen is equivalent to "pipe:0". It will take the pipe as input.

Comment: @mklement0 thanks for the answer. It worked. I was reluctant about the 'type', since it was used for merely text files. But it worked on .bmp files.